# Simplest way possible to return key of an array matching a children prop in es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array countries [{id:1,name:"France"},{id:name:"Italy"}];

What is the shortest way to write something like that in pure ES6 and assign element to a value ?

```
this.countries.map((item, key) => {
   if(data.country.id == item.id){
       this.country = this.countries[key];
   }
});
```

So far we found this way but it's not pretty :

```
this.country = this.countries.filter((item) => item.id == data.country.id)[0];
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Your array is malformed. It should be `[{id:1,name:"France"},{id:2,name:"Italy"}]` - Also you don't need to provide an ID for the country considering arrays do that.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way would be :-)

```
this.country = this.countries.find((item) => item.id == data.country.id);
```